# Cordova AngularJS Ionic Tabs contents are overlapping on first load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm new to Cordova angularjs and ionic. I am trying to display a page with tabs. This is working but the problem is when page is loaded first, tabs are overlapping each other for seconds and then it displays normally afterwards.

Here's my code:

**index.html**

```
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-icon-top tabs-color-positive">
            <ion-tab title="News" icon="ion-home" href="#home">
                <div id="home">
                    <ion-pane>
                        <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
                          <h1 class="title">Home</h1>
                        </ion-header-bar>

                        <ion-content class="scroll-content ionic-scroll has-header has-tabs has-tabs-icon-top">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                                        This is a basic Card which contains an item that has wrapping text.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                                        This is a basic Card which contains an item that has wrapping text.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </ion-content>
                    </ion-pane>
                </div>
            </ion-tab>
            <ion-tab title="Report" icon="ion-compose" href="#report">
                <div id="report"></div>
            </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
```

**app.js:**

```
 app.run(function ($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaNetwork, $cordovaBatteryStatus, $cordovaLocalNotification, $cordovaPush) {

$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
  if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  }
  if (window.StatusBar) {
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
  }

  $cordovaLocalNotification.registerPermission().then(function () {
    //alert("registered");
  }, function () {
    //alert("denied registration");
  });

  var iosConfig = {
    "badge": true,
    "sound": true,
    "alert": true
  };
  $cordovaPush.register(iosConfig).then(function (result) {
    //alert("device token: " + result.deviceToken);
  }, function (error) {
    //alert("error " + error);
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function (event, notification) {
    if (notification.alert) {
      navigator.notification.alert(notification.alert);
    }
    if (notification.sound) {
      var snd = new Media(event.sound);
      snd.play();
    }
    if (notification.badge) {
      $cordovaPush.setBadgeNumber(notification.badge).then(function (result) {
        // Success!
      }, function (err) {
        // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
      });
    }
  });


  $rootScope.$on("$cordovaNetwork:offline", function (event, result) {
    alert("Device is now Offline!");
  });


  $rootScope.$on("$cordovaNetwork:online", function (event, result) {
    alert("Device is Online!");
  });

  $rootScope.$on("$cordovaBatteryStatus:status", function (event, status) {
    //alert("status: " + status);
  })
})
})

  app.config(function ($ionicConfigProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $cordovaFacebookProvider, $cordovaAppRateProvider, $cordovaInAppBrowserProvider) {

if (!window.cordova) {
  var appID = 1234567890;
  var version = "v2.0"; // or leave blank and default is v2.0
  //$cordovaFacebookProvider.browserInit(appID, version);
}

var browserOptions = {
  location: "yes",
  toolbar: "yes"
};

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  var preferences = {
    iosURL: "some URL",
    appName: 'APP NAME',
    language: 'fr'
  };
  $cordovaAppRateProvider.setPreferences(preferences);
}, false);

$cordovaInAppBrowserProvider.setDefaultOptions(browserOptions);

$stateProvider
  .state('menu', {
    url: "/menu",
    templateUrl: "app/menu.html"
  })

  .state('about', {
    url: "/about",
    templateUrl: "app/about.html"
  })

  .state('appAvailability', {
    url: '/appAvailability',
    templateUrl: 'app/appAvailability/appAvailability.html',
    controller: "AppAvailabilityCtrl"
  })

  .state('appRate', {
    url: '/appRate',
    templateUrl: 'app/appRate/appRate.html',
    controller: "AppRateCtrl"
  })


  .state('barcodeScanner', {
    url: '/barcodeScanner',
    templateUrl: 'app/barcodeScanner/barcodeScanner.html',
    controller: "BarcodeScannerCtrl"
  })

  .state('batteryStatus', {
    url: '/batteryStatus',
    templateUrl: 'app/batteryStatus/batteryStatus.html',
    controller: "BatteryStatusCtrl"
  })

  .state('beacon', {
    url: '/beacon',
    templateUrl: 'app/beacon/beacon.html',
    controller: "BeaconCtrl"
  })

  .state('camera', {
    url: '/camera',
    templateUrl: 'app/camera/camera.html',
    controller: "CameraCtrl"
  })

  .state('clipboard', {
    url: '/clipboard',
    templateUrl: 'app/clipboard/clipboard.html',
    controller: "ClipboardCtrl"
  })

  .state('contacts', {
    url: '/contacts',
    templateUrl: 'app/contacts/contacts.html',
    controller: "ContactsCtrl"
  })


  .state('datePicker', {
    url: '/datePicker',
    templateUrl: 'app/datePicker/datePicker.html',
    controller: "DatePickerCtrl"
  })

  .state('device', {
    url: '/device',
    templateUrl: 'app/device/device.html',
    controller: "DeviceCtrl"
  })

  .state('deviceMotion', {
    url: '/deviceMotion',
    templateUrl: 'app/deviceMotion/deviceMotion.html',
    controller: "DeviceMotionCtrl"
  })


  .state('deviceOrientation', {
    url: '/deviceOrientation',
    templateUrl: 'app/deviceOrientation/deviceOrientation.html',
    controller: "DeviceOrientationCtrl"
  })

  .state('dialogs', {
    url: '/dialogs',
    templateUrl: 'app/dialogs/dialogs.html',
    controller: "DialogsCtrl"
  })

  .state('emailComposer', {
    url: '/emailComposer',
    templateUrl: 'app/emailComposer/emailComposer.html',
    controller: "EmailComposerCtrl"
  })

  .state('facebook', {
    url: '/facebook',
    templateUrl: 'app/facebook/facebook.html',
    controller: "FacebookCtrl"
  })

  .state('file', {
    url: '/file',
    templateUrl: 'app/file/file.html',
    controller: "FileCtrl"
  })

  .state('fileTransfer', {
    url: '/fileTransfer',
    templateUrl: 'app/fileTransfer/fileTransfer.html',
    controller: "FileTransferCtrl"
  })

  .state('fileOpener2', {
    url: '/fileOpener2',
    templateUrl: 'app/fileOpener2/fileOpener2.html',
    controller: "FileOpener2Ctrl"
  })

  .state('flashlight', {
    url: '/flashlight',
    templateUrl: 'app/flashlight/flashlight.html',
    controller: "FlashlightCtrl"
  })

  .state('geolocation', {
    url: '/geolocation',
    templateUrl: 'app/geolocation/geolocation.html',
    controller: "GeolocationCtrl"
  })

  .state('globalization', {
    url: '/global',
    templateUrl: 'app/globalization/globalization.html',
    controller: "GlobalizationCtrl"
  })

  .state('googleAnalytics', {
    url: '/googleAnalytics',
    templateUrl: 'app/googleAnalytics/googleAnalytics.html',
    controller: "GoogleAnalyticsCtrl"
  })

  .state('healthkit', {
    url: '/healthkit',
    templateUrl: 'app/healthkit/healthkit.html',
    controller: "HealthKitCtrl"
  })

  .state('inAppBrowser', {
    url: '/inAppBrowser',
    templateUrl: 'app/inAppBrowser/inAppBrowser.html',
    controller: "InAppBrowserCtrl"
  })

  .state('localNotification', {
    url: '/localNotification',
    templateUrl: 'app/localNotification/localNotification.html',
    controller: "LocalNotificationCtrl"
  })

  .state('media', {
    url: '/media',
    templateUrl: 'app/media/media.html',
    controller: "MediaCtrl"
  })

  .state('network', {
    url: '/network',
    templateUrl: 'app/network/network.html',
    controller: "NetworkCtrl"
  })

  .state('preferences', {
    url: '/preferences',
    templateUrl: 'app/preferences/preferences.html',
    controller: "PreferencesCtrl"
  })

  .state('printer', {
    url: '/printer',
    templateUrl: 'app/printer/printer.html',
    controller: "PrinterCtrl"
  })

  .state('pushNotifications', {
    url: '/pushNotifications',
    templateUrl: 'app/pushNotifications/pushNotifications.html',
    controller: "PushNotificationsCtrl"
  })

  .state('socialSharing', {
    url: '/socialSharing',
    templateUrl: 'app/socialSharing/socialSharing.html',
    controller: "SocialSharingCtrl"
  })

  .state('sqlite', {
    url: '/sqlite',
    templateUrl: 'app/sqlite/sqlite.html',
    controller: "SqliteCtrl"
  })


  .state('statusbar', {
    url: '/statusbar',
    templateUrl: 'app/statusbar/statusbar.html',
    controller: "StatusbarCtrl"
  })


  .state('toast', {
    url: '/toast',
    templateUrl: 'app/toast/toast.html',
    controller: "ToastCtrl"
  })

  .state('touchid', {
    url: '/touchid',
    templateUrl: 'app/touchid/touchid.html',
    controller: "TouchIDCtrl"
  })

  .state('vibration', {
    url: '/vibration',
    templateUrl: 'app/vibration/vibration.html',
    controller: "VibrationCtrl"
  })

  .state('upsPushNotifications', {
    url: '/upsPushNotifications',
    templateUrl: 'app/upsPushNotifications/pushNotifications.html',
    controller: "UpsPushNotificationsCtrl"
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/menu');


$ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom'); // Set to bottom
});
```

What do you think is wrong with my code above? I would gladly appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload a screenshot of how they are overlapped? The code seems to be fine

Answer (score 0):

Upload your css for the tabs and how you linked them to the page. It's probably a css problem loading late